# Eclipse debugger not working

Tags: java, eclipse, variables

I'm trying to use the eclipse debugger to fix some code, and I need to see when a variable changes (or if it does). When I go into the debugger, I have the variables tab already open but it doesn't show any variables. I looked at a YouTube video on this but for them the variable was already there and showing.
Where I initialize it (I know I could have used an array):

```
    static char s1 =' ';
    static char s2 =' ';
    static char s3 =' ';
    static char s4 =' ';
    static char s5 =' ';
    static char s6 =' ';
    static char s7 =' ';
    static char s8 =' ';
    static char s9 =' ';
```

And the biggest part I use it in:

```
    else if(place==5){
            if(s5==' '){
                s5 = 'X';
                if(s1=='X'){
                    if(s9=='X'){
                        System.out.println("X wins!");
                        CreateBoard(s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9);
                        a = 1;
                    }
                }if(s3=='X'){
                    if(s7=='X'){
                        System.out.println("X wins!");
                        CreateBoard(s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9);
                        a = 1;
                    }
                }if(s2=='X'){
                    if(s8=='X'){
                        System.out.println("X wins!");
                        CreateBoard(s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9);
                        a = 1;
                    }
                }if(s4=='X'){
                    if(s6=='X'){
                        System.out.println("X wins!");
                        CreateBoard(s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9);
                        a = 1;
                    }
                }

            }



        }
```

Comment: Do you have any breakpoints set?

Comment: I would be hard (not impossible) because all of my code is a loop (except for defining something) and i need the loop to run until it is supposed to stop.

Comment: Well without a breakpoint you aren't going to see anything.

Comment: I added a breakpoint and its still not working

Comment: Just use print statements everywhere and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

To see variables and values, you need to be sure to select one of the lines in the call stack.  Sometimes the UI fails to select a line in the stack and you don't see any variables or values.

Comment: I did. and even looked how to do it up and I didn't do it wrong (according to them)

Answer (score 0):

Try the Expressions tab, where you can enter which variables or method calls you want to evaluate. Also, it might help to post a screenshot and/or what line the debugger is on.

Comment: I've already tried the expressions tab, I put it in and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Check the local menu for the `Variables` view and make sure **Show Static Variables** is enabled. They are frequently used for constants, not changed, and just take up space in the view.

[image: local menu]

Comment: I did do that trying to figure it out

Comment: If that solved it, you should Accept an answer. Otherwise, you should pursue it further with more details (like what this loop is that you mention, and making sure you're launching the application using `Debug` rather than `Run`).